# Joomla component development / css on com_config (options dialog)

Tags: css, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am developing a Joomla extension (component with additional plugins and modules) - it is named jDBexport.

Is there an elegant way to style the **[Options] dialog** (e.g. the view that opens with the content of the components config.xml file). The best way would be if I can add a specific css-file to be loaded when the component configuration is called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link, it will help you https://docs.joomla.org/Radio_form_field_type

```html
<field name="myradiovalue" type="radio" default="0" label="Select an option" description="" class="btn-group btn-group-yesno">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
</field>
```